# How to change the location of a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a problem, im making me own custom SharePoint webpart.
everything is going well, but the problem is that i can't figure out how to change the location of the textboxes and labels.
anyone knows how i can change the locations?

I am trying to accomplish it in C#.

problem SOLVED.

Comment: Language? Application? Any information that describes what you are using would be very helpful is providing the right direction for you.

Comment: im trying to accomplish it in C#, it's a webpart for sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of component ids. set position of that particular component.

Answer (score 0):

"How to change the location of the textboxes and labels"

In this example i'm using a Button (Action performed on Button Click) and i am also adding how to Generate a TextBox and a Label (When you press this Button). 
Just because this is usually a common process within setting locations to a control.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Settings to generate a New TextBox
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();   // Create the Variable for TextBox
        txt.Name = "MyTextBoxID";      // Identify your new TextBox

        // Create Variables to Define "X" and "Y" Locations
        var txtLocX = txt.Location.X;
        var txtLocY = txt.Location.Y;

        //Set your TextBox Location Here
        txtLocX = 103;
        txtLocY = 74;

        // This adds a new TextBox
        this.Controls.Add(txt);

        // Now do the same for Labels

        // Settings to generate a New Label
        Label lbl = new Label();   // Create the Variable for Label
        lbl.Name = "MyNewLabelID"; // Identify your new Label

        // Create Variables to Define "X" and "Y" Locations
        var lblLocX = lbl.Location.X;
        var lblLoxY = lbl.Location.Y;

        //Set your Label Location Here
        lblLocX = 34;
        lblLoxY = 77;

        // Adds a new Label
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }
}
```

Note: This is just an example and will not work after postback.

I hope this answers to your and everyone's question.